# Dash Plotly: Show date in output after update

Tags: python, callback, plotly, dashboard

[the screenshot of the dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPuLO.png)

I would like to output the current selected date (this is already achieved) and also the date after clicking "- 7 days" or "+ 7 days" button, if they are clicked.

The layout looks like this:

```
dbc.Collapse(children=[ dbc.Label("Current: ", className="my-label"),

                                        dcc.DatePickerSingle(
                                            id='my-date-picker-single',
                                            #children=['Current:'],
                                            min_date_allowed=date(1995, 8, 5),
                                            max_date_allowed=date(2021, 12, 31),
                                            initial_visible_month=date(2020, 12, 1),
                                            date=date(2020, 12, 1),
                                            display_format='DD-MM-YYYY',
                                            calendar_orientation='horizontal',
                                            with_portal=False,
                                            style={'zIndex': 10, "background-color": "#2C3E50", "color": "#FFFFFF",
                                                   "width": '65%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'font-size': '0.8rem',"border-radius": "4px"},
                                            className="dash-bootstrap mx-2"
                                        ),
                       html.Br(),
                       dbc.Row(children=[

                                dbc.ButtonGroup(children=[
                                    dbc.Button(id='backward_button', className='btn btn-primary split-button', children=[
                                        html.Span([html.I(className='fas fa-fw fa-angle-double-left'), " -7 Days " ]),
                                    ], ),
                                    dbc.Button(id='forward_button', className='btn btn-primary split-button', children=[
                                        html.Span([" +7 Days ", html.I(className='fas fa-fw fa-angle-double-right')]),
                                    ], )
                                ]),

                       ],
                        className="btn-group mx-1 mt-2",
                       ),
                       html.Br(),
                       html.Div(id='my-output'),
                    ],

    id="submenu-1-collapse",
),
```

I tried the following code, but it is not working.

```
    @app.callback(Output('my-date-picker-single', 'date'), [Input('store', 'data')], [State('my-date-picker-single', 'date')])
def set_calendar_date(data_store, cal_date):
    '''
    Anpassen des im Date-Picker gezeigten Datums an tatsächliches Basisdatum  der Prognose
    Match the date shown in the date picker to the actual forecast base date
    '''
    base_date = pd.to_datetime(data_store['base_date']).to_pydatetime()
    cal_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(cal_date[0:10],'%Y-%m-%d')
    if base_date == cal_date:
        raise PreventUpdate
    return base_date

@app.callback([Output('store', 'data')],
              [Input('backward_button', 'n_clicks'), Input('forward_button', 'n_clicks'), Input('my-date-picker-single', 'date')],
              [State('store', 'data')])
def time_change(_b, _f, cal_date, data_store):
    '''
    Anpassen des Basisprognosedatums in Abhängigkeit von Inputs
    Adjust baseline forecast date depending on inputs
    :return:
    '''
    ctx = dash.callback_context.triggered
    print('u:'+str(ctx))
    trigger_list = [val['prop_id'].split('.')[0] for val in ctx]
    base_date: pd._libs.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(data_store['base_date'])

    if len({'my-date-picker-single', 'backward_button', 'forward_button'}.intersection(trigger_list)) > 0:
        if 'my-date-picker-single' in trigger_list:
            cal_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(cal_date[0:10], '%Y-%m-%d')
            base_date = pd.Timestamp(cal_date - datetime.timedelta(days=cal_date.weekday()))
        if 'backward_button' in trigger_list:
            base_date -= datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        if 'forward_button' in trigger_list:
            base_date += datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        data_store['base_date'] = base_date
    return [data_store]


@app.callback(
    Output(component_id='my-output', component_property='children'),
    Input(component_id='my-date-picker-single', component_property='date')
    #[Input(component_id='my-date-picker-single', component_property='date'), Input('backward_button', 'n_clicks'), Input('forward_button', 'n_clicks')],
    #[State('store', 'data')]
)
def update_output_div(input_value):
    return f'Output: {input_value}'
    #return u'Previous date is "{}" and new date is "{}"'.format(input_value, data_store)
```

I just started with dash plotly this week and so any advice would be very much helpful.